# Is it possible to use Value Object as id for Entity with Doctrine ODM?

Tags: php, doctrine-odm, ddd-repositories

I have `Subscription` entity, which represents one of many-to-many relations between users in Twitter-like following model. It has surrogate ID to ensure the uniqueness of relation, which is represented by Value Object `SubscriptionId`. `SubscriptionId` is persisted as a `MongoBinData`. Here is the XML description:

```
<document name="Subscription"
          collection="users.subscriptions"
          repository-class="SubscriptionRepository">
    <field name="id" id="true" type="User.Subscription.Id"/>
    <field name="u" fieldName="userId" type="User.Id"/>
    <field name="t" fieldName="subscribedTo" type="User.Id"/>
    <field name="d" fieldName="dateTime" type="PreciseDateTime"/>
</document>
```

I set `id` field to `Subscription` in constructor manually. The problem is that ODM forces upsert operation instead of insert for new entities with IDs. Thus I have no chance to detect duplication (domain events will be raised twice, etc.). This code executes without duplicate exception:

```
$sub = new Subscription($subscriberId, $subscribedToId);

$dm->persist($sub);
$dm->flush();

$dm->clear();

$dm->persist($sub);
$dm->flush();
```

I tried to use custom id generator instead of setting `id` in constructor. But for some reason ODM ignored my `type="User.Subscription.Id"` and treated ID type as `custom_id`. My entity had instance of `MongoBinData` instead of desired `SubscriptionId`.

I'm looking for a graceful way to achieve the goals:

1. VO as entity's id
2. Duplication exception when persisting new entity with existing ID

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm currently stuck.

Comment: @Oddman, no, I gave up : (

Comment: @Oddman, now I use string `<field name="id" id="true"/>` combined with unique index by `u` and `t`.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out - it's simply how you setup the mapping. Basically, you register a new "type" say its UserId as a value object. You then create a DQL mapping of that type which knows how to fetch the actual value and does the conversion (Ie. if it's a string UUID, then you'd get the string value to be sent).

It then also knows how to convert it back. Took me a while to figure out how it worked, but got there eventually. So now I have value objects for each type of id (user id, post id, content id.etc.).

Comment: Do you create IDs manually (eg. in constructor) or ODM creates it for you?

Comment: I create all my ids manually, as I often want control over them.